# How can I store html in a MySQL table using python

Tags: python, html, mysql, phrase

Okay here is my code. Hopefully you can help me. I am using the MySQL lib called MySQLdb.

```
    def createNick(self, user, nick):
       try: # TRY STATEMENT HERE SO THE NICK CAN BE RECREATED
           db = m.connect("host", "user", "password", "database")
           cur = db.cursor()
           cur.execute("CREATE TABLE nick_%s(name TEXT NOT NULL)" % user.lower())
           cur.execute('INSERT INTO nick_%s(name) VALUES("%s")' % (user.lower(), nick))
           db.commit()
       except:
           db = m.connect("host", "user", "password", "database")
           cur = db.cursor()
           cur.execute("DROP TABLE nick_%s" % user.lower())
           cur.execute("CREATE TABLE nick_%s(name TEXT NOT NULL)" % user.lower())
           cur.execute('INSERT INTO nick_%s(name) VALUES("%s")' % (user.lower(), nick))
           db.commit()
    def getNick(user):
           db = m.connect("host", "user", "password", "database")
           cur = db.cursor()
           cur.execute("SELECT * FROM nick_%s" % user.lower())
           nick = [nick[0] for nick in cur.fetchall()]
           try: # TRY STATEMENT HERE JUST INCASE USER DID NOT MAKE ONE
               return nick
           except:
               return user
  self.createNick("username","<font color='#FFFF'>nickname</font>")
  print self.getNick("username")
  output: <font color=#FFF>nickname</font>
```

My problem is, every time I call the function it won't phrase the HTML correctly. I tried everything, can you help?

Comment: What do you mean "phrase the HTML correctly"? Also, how about posting the HTML itself? Or at least a (relevant) snippet?

Comment: the html is what you see by "output:" and it replaces the quotes and leaves the rest as you see here   <font color=#FFF>nickname</font> and output:

Comment: Is this a web app?  Thought about using an MVC framework like Django?

Comment: Are you giving every user their own table in the Database? Why?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do that, I would use a specific data type for XML so that I save HTML to a datatype of type XML. Or I would not save HTML and insert the markup with a controller, or make my own midddleware language since it is usually not adviseable to save HTML in a database table.

Comment: its for a bot, but I do not know how to use XML. I  only know python and PHP. But I cant really use PHP for this.

Comment: sadly i'm not to great at MySQL. So creating tables seemed easier because i could just drop the tables. If you have a better way please let me know.